# Isolating Digital IO from Microcontroller

Tags: pcb-design, dc-dc-converter, embedded, hardware, optoelectronics

I have designed an Embedded System in which the PCB has both Non-Isolated and Isolated DC DC converter.

[image]

I am taking a 24V DC Supply from a PLC Device. Converting it to 3.3V with a Non -Isolated DC DC Converter. However, I want to control a Relay (Output) and also Sense for Contact Closure (Voltage free input/Alarm input) with in the same device.

As shown in the block diagram, I have Isolated the 3.3V using a separate unregulated Isolated DC DC converter for Digital IO operations. I am using an optocoupler to isolate the Digital IO from the microcontroller circuitry.

My questions are:

1. I want to Control the Relay using the 24V tapped from the input of Non-Isolated DC DC converter. Does this configuration provide Isolation? or Should I use only the Isolated 3.3V to control the relay? (which won't catch relay startup voltage)
2. Since I have potential free Inputs, I can use either ground or positive voltage to sense the NC contacts of a relay. I think the 24V tapped from the Inputs will provide long distance sensing proper. But what happens to the Isolation?
3. This device will be DIN Rail mountable. If I have to use chassis ground, which ground should I share with Chassis ground? or is it even necessary as we will use only plastic enclosure?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Update:
Here is the schematic of Input and Output:
[image]

Comment: What relay? What do you mean by "tapped"? Isolation from what? Could you add your [potential] relay setup to the diagram?

Answer (score 1):

> I want to Control the Relay using the 24V tapped from the input of
>   Non-Isolated DC DC converter. Does this configuration provide
>   Isolation?

No it doesn't provide isolation because it bypasses the isolation provided by the opto-isolators. However, if you can rely on coil/contact isolation then you have isolation but, that then begs the question as to why you are using opto-couplers to drive relays.

> or Should I use only the Isolated 3.3V to control the
>   relay? (which won't catch relay startup voltage)

Try making your isolated DC/DC converter more like 24 volts or 12 volts and have this power the opto AND the relays. If you need feedback signals to the microprocessor then that might be a good reason for the opto-couplers.

> Since I have potential free Inputs, I can use either ground or
>   positive voltage to sense the NC contacts of a relay. I think the 24V
>   tapped from the Inputs will provide long distance sensing proper. But
>   what happens to the Isolation?

You lose isolation - if you want to feedback relay activities to your micro you need isolated feedback circuitry (maybe consider using the ADuM5401 range from ADI) or use the opto-couplers but you need an isolated supply to the relays: -

[image]

> This device will be DIN Rail mountable. If I have to use chassis
>   ground, which ground should I share with Chassis ground? or is it even
>   necessary as we will use only plastic enclosure?

If you were to use any external ground it has to be connected to your microprocessor ground for at least EMC reasons I would say. After all, your output relays are isolated and this means they are also isolated from ground unless wired that way in certain applications of your module.